# Nilpotent in ring Mn( R)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A,B \in M_n(R)$. $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent .

Is it true that "$A+B$ is invertible"?

I think zero is eigenvalue of $A+B$.$A+B$ is not invertible?

Comment: Have you tried some examples? This always helps. In this case, you might want to look at the case $A = B$.

Comment: Remark : If $Av = 0$ and $Bw = 0$ for some vectors $v,w$, there is no reason for the existence of a vector $u$ with $(A+B)u = 0$, since in general $v \neq w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not always true that $A+B$ is invertible: just take $A$ and $B$ to be the matrix with all zeroes. For a less trivial counterexample, take them both to be any strictly upper triangular matrices.

Regarding your attempt: sometimes $A+B$ is invertible and so zero might *not* be an eigenvalue of $A+B$. For example, this happens in $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Both of these are nilpotent, but $A+B$ is invertible.

Comment: Is A+B nilpotent?

Comment: Sometimes $A+B$ is nilpotent (for example, in the first paragraph of my answer), but sometimes it is not (the example in the second paragraph).